# In 1 Sam. 20:25, why does עַל-מוֹשָׁבוֹ appear to have two te'amim?

Tags: trop-cantillation

I understand that there is a rule (with rare exceptions) that a single word cannot bear two Masoretic accents. However, I have not seen [1 Sam. 20:25](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt08a20.htm#25) listed as one of the exceptions:

> וַיֵּ֣שֶׁב הַ֠מֶּלֶךְ **עַל־מ֨וֹשָׁב֜וֹ** כְּפַ֣עַם ׀ בְּפַ֗עַם אֶל־מוֹשַׁב֙ הַקִּ֔יר וַיָּ֨קָם֙ יְה֣וֹנָתָ֔ן וַיֵּ֥שֶׁב אַבְנֵ֖ר מִצַּ֣ד שָׁא֑וּל וַיִּפָּקֵ֖ד מְק֥וֹם דָּוִֽד׃
>
> And the king sat **upon his seat,** as at other times, even upon the seat by the wall; and Jonathan stood up, and Abner sat by Saul's side; but David's place was empty.

I have also read that *azla* "occasionally replaces *metheg* to mark secondary stress," but I am not confident that this can logically apply here (if so how?).

What I wasn't understanding was that, with the preposition joined by maqqef, the "secondary accent" syllable receiving the kadma is not "the first syllable of the word." For [Wickes, p. 113](https://archive.org/stream/treatiseonacce00wick#page/112/mode/2up), says, "Azla may take the place of light Metheg in the same word with Geresh (only of course not on the first letter)." If this is a valid rule, then the word *moshav* with the two accents would be illegal, but I suppose *`al-moshav* is another animal.

How common is the phenomenon exemplified by the accentuation of the word *moshav* here?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please take a look at our [tour] when you get a chance where you’ll find some useful information about the site. More directly related to your question: where do you know this rule from? And where do you see this list of exceptions? Maybe it’s just not typically done, but it’s okay when it is?

Comment: I'm not sure what you find confusing about your rule. There would be a secondary accent on מו and it converts to an Kadma as you said

Comment: Thank you. I suppose what I wasn't understanding was that, with the preposition joined by maqqef, the "secondary accent" syllable receiving the kadma is not "the first syllable of the word." For [Wickes, p. 113,](https://archive.org/stream/treatiseonacce00wick#page/112/mode/2up) says, "Azla may take the place of light Metheg in the same word with Geresh (only of course not on the first letter." If this is a valid rule, then the word moshav with the two accents would be illegal, but I suppose `al-moshav is another animal.

Comment: Kadma V'azla appears numerous times on the same word throughout Tanac"h. These two notes are "pairs", as are a number of others. It's not unusual to see trope pairs on the same word. In this week's parsha (Pinchas), see Bemidbar 28:26. You'll see two words each with two notes.

Comment: Thank you for the Bemidbar 28:26 reference. In both of those examples, a word of 3+ syllables more naturally needs a secondary accent. I still do wonder how common it can be to have a trope pair on a two-syllable word like "moshav." But my question is effectively answered--it turns out to be a very ignorant one, as I am only starting to notice the less frequent features of the trope!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have mostly answered your question. For the purposes of cantillation, words that are connected with a maqaf are treated as one word.

Thus, על־מושבו (a) has a syllable (מו) that's appropriate for a light accent (געיה קלה), (b) which is not on the first syllable (because על is the first syllable), (c) the word is not preceded by a conjunctive accent. R. Breuer (in טעמי המקרא section ג.10-11) says that in this situation, the light accent becomes a kadma (or azla, if you will) only when not in the domain of a revia. Here, however, revia does follow, and R. Breuer lists this among several exceptions (along with Lev 14:51, Deut 25:19, and Sam 1:4:18). He suggests that perhaps the transformation still occurs when t'lisha g'dola precedes, even with a revia following. However, he lists another 14 exceptions to *that* suggestion, so at the end we're left with a general rule and some exceptions — whether your verse is an exception or not is up in the air.

Overall, using [this site](https://cwoolf.neocities.org/openBible/oshb) as a database (while imperfect, it's close enough for generalities): the Torah contains 37 occurrences of geresh and kadma on the same word, as compared to 1076 plain geresh and 509 gershayim; thus, about 2.3% of geresh/gershayim occurrences in the Torah have a kadma on the same word. You can check the other books yourself, but I imagine you'll find a similar spread.